# Xamarin forms - side menu left bar, fragment and listview

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Is there an example of Project Xamarin forms (android/ios) with a side left menu bar (like example when you create Project using Android.Support.V4 (with fragment) that uses ListView?

I am trying to insert a listview but without success when using Fragment.

I'm not finding any example here and Google.

Maybe I was not knowing the correct search term.

Comment: Are you trying to use MasterDetail page? https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/master-detail-page/

Comment: great. I believe this will help me a lot. Thanks. 
How do I mark and give point to you?

Comment: I have added it as an answer with more information. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a [MasterDetail Page](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/master-detail-page/) for the same.

It is a page that manages two related pages of information – a master page that presents items, and a detail page that presents details about items on the master page. This article demonstrates how to use a MasterDetailPage and navigate between its pages of information.

```
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MasterDetailPageNavigation;assembly=MasterDetailPageNavigation"
                  x:Class="MasterDetailPageNavigation.MainPage">
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <local:MasterPage x:Name="masterPage" />
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage>
            <x:Arguments>
                <local:ContactsPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

You can find the sample code [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Navigation/MasterDetailPage/).